# jQuery- How to properly test whether input field is blank? By value or length?

Tags: jquery

In doing some jQuery validation, I would like to test whether or not the form field was left blank. Which is the best/most stable way of doing this- by testing that the value is not blank or by testing the length is not zero?

```
if (inputValue != '') { // Do something
```

OR

```
if (inputValue.length > 0) { // Do something
```

Comment: I would have used `!!inputValue` which means that you check if `inputValue` is not undefined or not null or not blank.

Comment: @dtlvd: The OP says it's from a form field, so it's a string.

Comment: i think in this case trim needed

Comment: @SanthoshNayak: Trim would be needed in both cases, if trim is needed. `" ".length` is `> 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said `inputValue` comes from a form field, and you're using `length`, so we know it's a string

Your two examples are equally stable. Neither is "best" except according to personal opinion.

Also note that an empty string is falsy and a non-empty string is truthy, so you can also do

```
if (inputValue)
```

Again, not "best" or "non-best," it's up to you which of the three you prefer.

Additionally, string `length` cannot be negative, and `0` is falsy while all positive values are truthy, so you can do:

```
if (inputValue.length)
```

That brings us up to four. Take your pick. They all do the same thing in different ways.

---

Depending on your definition of "empty," you might also want to throw a `trim` in there:

```
if (inputValue.trim() != '')

// or

if (inputValue.trim().length > 0)

// or

if (inputValue.trim().length)

// or

if (inputValue.trim())
```

Comment: In case of check trim.. if type of inputValue is not string then we have to convert it in string

Comment: @HareshVidja: Yes, but we know it's a string from the question.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to check consider spaces as blank string then you haveto use trim() method

```
if(new String(inputValue).trim())
{
   // it not blank
}
else
{
    // it is blank
}
```

Comment: Am Agree with T.J. Crowder case for test best case

Comment: There's no reason to do `new String(...)`, simply `if (inputValue.trim())` is sufficient.

Comment: I have replied for this answer in your answer comment.

Comment: If you want to convert a non-string to a string, `new String(...)` is not how you do that. `String(...)` is how you do that. `String`, when called without `new`, coerces its argument to a string primitive. `new String` creates a string **object**. You almost never want to create string objects explicitly in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can also use `if(!inputValue){...}` as empty strings evaluate as false.

In principle I believe to all intents and purposes both are equally stable, ordinarily I would go for length checks but with input fields where you have a default value it helps to be able to duplicate the default in the string check - so you're not rereading the default as a user entered value.

For this reason if you're using jQuery you can use `.change()` https://api.jquery.com/change/ which you might find to be more robust?